# Csharp sparse matrix library similar to R matrix library?

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Anyone know of any good sparse matrix library?  I need it for doing kronecker products and multiplication on large sparse matrices (10,000 x 10,000).

Right now we are using R, which handles them pretty well.  Unfortunately we can't put R into production so looking for alternatives.  I've been playing around with Math.net numerics, but it seems a bit slow.

Comment: Yes, the Kronecker product on sparse matrices would indeed be slow in Math.NET Numerics (as of today) since it is still lacking a proper sparse override (i.e. currently dense). I've just opened [issue 42](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/42) on this.

Answer (score 0):

A .NET open-source alternative to *Math.NET Numerics* is [MetaNumerics](http://www.meta-numerics.net/). Most recent downloads can be accessed [here](http://metanumerics.codeplex.com/releases/view/63906). *MetaNumerics* has less functionality than *Math.NET Numerics*  and it has not been updated for a year or so, but it does provide some sparse matrix functionality according to the [API documentation](http://www.meta-numerics.net/Documentation/index.html).

There is also [sparse matrix support](http://www.alglib.net/matrixops/sparse.php) in [ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/), which is available for multiple platforms including .NET. ALGLIB comes with both an open-source and commercial license.

I do not know if either of these libraries provide faster sparse matrix computation than *Math.NET Numerics*, though.